# datatable row check string contain another string in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a data table inside my program where it listed out a some data seperately in 8 rows.

My question is how can I check if there is a string exist in the string **within** the data in the row 5.

Here's what i coded so far:

```
String data_source = null;

data_source = my_datatable.Rows[0][5].ToString();

for (int i = 0; i < my_datatable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (data_source.Contains("<script") == true)
    {
        my_datatable.Rows[i][5] = "Cross Site Scripting";
    }
    else if (data_source.Contains("()") == true)
    {
        my_datatable.Rows[i][5] = "SQL Injection";
    }
    else if (data_source.Contains("\\..\\") == true)
    {
        my_datatable.Rows[i][5] = "Unicode Attack";
    }
    else if (data_source.Contains("http/www") == true)
    {
        my_datatable.Rows[i][5] = "Proxy Attack";
    }
    else if (data_source.Contains("cgi-bin") == true)
    {
        my_datatable.Rows[i][5] = "Cgi-Bin";
    }
    else
    {
        my_datatable.Rows[i][5] = "Normal";
    }    
}
```

But it seem the result it only read only the "Cross Site Scripting"

Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Can You post value of `my_datatable.Rows[0][5].ToString()` ?

Comment: you're always using first row and sixth column as `data_source`. Your first comparison is whether that `data_source` contains text `<script`, and it does :) Maybe you meant to iterate through all the rows, not just the first one...

Comment: https://ibb.co/c2jubQ did you mean this? Sorry, i'm really new to c# @AmitKumar

Comment: please edit your answer and put additional code or explanation there.

Comment: Yea, supposedly i need to iterate through all rows. Do you have idea what i need to change there, cause i really lost right now :/ Really sorry @nino

Comment: Just a comment on the conditions: **data_source.Contains("<script")** is a boolean. The value of it is just the same as **data_source.Contains("<script") == true** and **data_source.Contains("<script") != false** for that matter. You can skip all the **== true** and the code would look cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: Oh okay! Noted. Thank you for your reply :) @Palle Due

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're always using first row, I'm guessing you shoul move variable `data_source` inside your loop, like this:

```
String data_source = null;

for (int i = 0; i < my_datatable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    //put data_source here
    data_source = my_datatable.Rows[i][5].ToString();

    //... rest of your code...
    if (data_source.Contains("<script") == true)
    {
        my_datatable.Rows[i][5] = "Cross Site Scripting";
    }
    // etc...
```

Comment: @AliffM. marking answer as a solution is a way to say thanks :)

Comment: aw yea sorry, really never ask anything here actually, thanks again!! :) @nino